# Control Firefox in C#.net like Microsoft Internet Controls

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, visual-studio, firefox

I want to control Firefox tabs.  I have application that dynamically generate parameter of fixed url which I join with url and open on browser.

My problem is that on when I open any url from C# application by mentioned below code, it;s always open new tab instead of open url on same available tab.

```
Process.Start("firefox", "-url " + newurlscn.Text.ToString());
```

I want this function for chrome browser too.

I have Internet explorer code which work fine in IE, but need help for Firefox and chrome.

IE code:

```
 SHDocVw.ShellWindows pvShell = new ShellWindows();

                    SHDocVw.InternetExplorer pvWeb2 = null;
                    SHDocVw.ShellBrowserWindow pvweb3 = null;

                    int dwCount;

                    Boolean IsNavigate = false;

                    if (pvShell.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (dwCount = 0; dwCount < pvShell.Count; dwCount++)
                        {
                            var ovIE = pvShell.Item(dwCount);

                            if (((ovIE.LocationURL.IndexOf("callprocrm.com") > 0) && (ovIE.LocationURL.IndexOf("index.php") > 0)))
                            {
                                pvWeb2 = ovIE;

                                pvWeb2.Navigate(newurlscn.Text, ovIE, ovIE, ovIE, ovIE);
                                pvWeb2 = null;
                                IsNavigate = true;

                                break;

                            }
                        }

                        if (!IsNavigate)
                            Process.Start("iexplore", newurlscn.Text.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                        Process.Start("iexplore", newurlscn.Text.ToString());
```

I request to please help me as soon as possible.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: in firefox for full control you can use windows ui automation . do you want such option   ?

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.

Have you any example in Windows UI automation for any browser or windows ?

Comment: i sent an example that i got  . check

Answer (score 0):

This example search string inside search bar of firefox .if firefox not opened it will open with search option. if it already opened then it will bring it to front and search string again.. you can modify to achieve what you want . Use UI SPY tool to see windows ui automation practically

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Windows.Automation;
    using   Utils;
    namespace ControllerX.Executions
    {


        /// <summary>
        /// this class provide searching mechanisms
        /// </summary>
        class searching
        {

            public static void search(string Sentence)
            {

                if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty(Sentence)==true ) return; //no need to search empty value
                try
                {
                    searchInFireFox( Sentence);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Util.Debuglog(ex.Message);

                }//ex
            }


            private static AutomationElement cached;
            private static Process oldproc;

            /// <summary>
            /// search inside firefox
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="search_term"></param>
            private static  void searchInFireFox(string search_term)
            { 
                //search using firefox
                if (oldproc != null && oldproc.HasExited == false && cached!=null  )
                { 
                    object cachedPattern;
                    if (true == cached.TryGetCachedPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern, out cachedPattern))
                    {
                        InvokePattern iPattern = cachedPattern as InvokePattern  ;
                        Util.BringToFront(oldproc.MainWindowHandle);
                        if (iPattern != null) { iPattern.Invoke(); Util.SimulateMessage(search_term, true); }
                        Util.Debuglog("Invoked within cached :" + search_term);
                    }

                    return; 
                }//
                Process firefox = null;
                if (oldproc != null && oldproc.HasExited == true) { oldproc.Close();} 
                else { firefox=oldproc;Util.Debuglog("firefox=oldproc");  };
                cached = null;
                if (firefox==null) firefox = Util.FindByName("firefox"); 
                if (firefox != null)
                {
                    cached = InvokeAndCache(search_term,firefox.MainWindowHandle);
                   oldproc=firefox;
                }//if
                else if(   open_new(search_term)==false  )
                    Utils.ErrorHandle.notify_user("Could not search with firefox"); 

            }//


            private static bool open_new(string search_term)
            {
                bool ok = false;
                Process pfirefox = null;
                pfirefox =Util.StartProc(@"firefox.exe" ,
                                     "-new-tab -search \"" + search_term + "\"",
                                     null,
                                     false);
                oldproc = pfirefox;
                if (pfirefox != null) { ok = true; Util.Debuglog("opened in new : " + search_term); }
                return ok;
            }//open new

            private static AutomationElement InvokeAndCache(string search_term,IntPtr handle)
            {
                AutomationElement  search  = null;
                try
                {
                    AutomationElement aeDesktop = AutomationElement.RootElement;
                    AutomationElement aeBrowser = AutomationElement.FromHandle(handle);
                    // Set up the request.
                    CacheRequest cacheRequest = new CacheRequest();
                    cacheRequest.AutomationElementMode = AutomationElementMode.None;
                    cacheRequest.TreeFilter = Automation.ControlViewCondition;
                    cacheRequest.Add(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty);
                    cacheRequest.Add(InvokePattern.Pattern);
                    System.Windows.Automation.Condition conLocation = new OrCondition(
                        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Navigation Toolbar"),
                        new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Панель навигации") );//russian name of the tab
                    AutomationElement navigation = null;
                    navigation = aeBrowser.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, conLocation);
                    cacheRequest.Push();
                    if (navigation != null)
                    {
                        AutomationElementCollection elList = navigation.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));
                        if (elList != null && elList.Count > 1) 
                            search = elList[elList.Count - 1];
                    }
                        if (search != null)
                    {
                        Util.BringToFront(handle);
                        InvokePattern iPattern = search.GetCachedPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
                        cached = search;
                        if (iPattern != null) { 
                            iPattern.Invoke(); 
                      Util.SimulateMessage(search_term,true); //above what simulateMessage does
                    //  winform.SendKeys.SendWait(message);  
                     // winform.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                            Util.Debuglog("cached then invoked : " + search_term);
                        }//if iPattern
                    }//if
                    cacheRequest.Pop();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Util.Debuglog(ex.Message);
                }//try catch
                return search;
            }


        }//end class
    }
```

**util class that was used by class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
//using winform = System.Windows.Forms;
 using WindowsInput;
/*
 * author:qwr

 *
 * */
namespace Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Utility methods for using through the program
    /// </summary>
    class Util
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Starting external program
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="file_name">path of the executable file</param>
        /// <param name="arguments">arguments to be passed </param>
        /// <param name="hidden">options for showing windows</param>
        /// <returns>return Process if the function succeeds otherwise null</returns>
        public static Process StartProc(string file_name, string arguments,string workdir, bool hidden)
        {
            Process proc = null;
            try
            {
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                if (workdir!=null && workdir.Length>0) 
                    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = workdir;
                if (arguments != null && arguments.Length > 0) 
                    startInfo.Arguments = arguments;
                startInfo.FileName = file_name;  

                if (hidden == true)
                {
                    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                }//hidden
                proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
                proc.Start(); 
                Debuglog("startProc started " + file_name);

            }//try
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debuglog("startProc  " + file_name);
                Debuglog("startProc error :"+ ex.Message);
                proc = null;
            }//try-catch

            return proc;
        }//startproc

        /// <summary>
        /// Kill all instances of process by name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">name of process</param>
        public static void KillProc(string name)
        {
            Process[] Proclist = Process.GetProcessesByName(name);
            foreach (Process proc in Proclist)
            {
                proc.Kill();
            }//for
            return;

        }//killproc

        /// <summary>
        /// Kill Process
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="process"></param>
        public static void KillProc( Process process)
        {
            try
            {
                if (process != null && process.HasExited == false)
                {
                     process.Kill();
                     Util.Debuglog("trying to kill process..."+process.Id);
                }//if null
            }//try
            catch (Exception ex)
            {  
                Util.Debuglog("fail to kill");
                ex.Message.toLog();
                ex.StackTrace.toLog();
            }//try-catch

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds first occurence of the process instance by its name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">name of processed that will be searched</param>
        /// <returns>return Process on succed otherwise null</returns>
        public static Process FindByName(string name)
        {
            Process found = null;
            //need to find through name
            Process[] myProcess = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process p in myProcess)
                if (p.ProcessName == name) { found = p; break; }
            return found;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert unix time to C# date
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="unixTime"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DateTime  CSharpTime(double unixTime)
        {
          DateTime unixStartTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,DateTimeKind.Utc);
          return unixStartTime.AddSeconds(unixTime).ToLocalTime();
        }//ToCSharpTime

        /// <summary>
        /// Makes windows appear on the top
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">hadnle of window</param>
        public static void BringToFront(IntPtr handle)
        {
            native.WINDOWPLACEMENT wndP;
            native.GetWindowPlacement(handle, out wndP);
            if (wndP.ShowCmd == native.WindowShowStyle.ShowMinimized || wndP.ShowCmd == native.WindowShowStyle.Minimize)
                native.ShowWindow(handle, native.WindowShowStyle.ShowDefault);
            native.SetForegroundWindow(handle);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// simulating keyboard .
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">message that will be typed</param>
        /// <param name="enterKey">indicates if enter key will be send after message</param>
        /// <remarks>this function uses windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait
        /// for better performance you can use other simulators
        /// or direct text manipulation methods
        /// </remarks>
        public static void SimulateMessage(string message, bool enterKey)
        {
           // winform.SendKeys.SendWait(message); //calls application doevents inside
          //  if (enterKey) winform.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
            InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry(message);
            if (enterKey) InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
        }

        private static readonly object locker = new object(); 

        /// <summary>
        /// small log . debug only
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s"></param>
     // [ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")] 
        public static void Debuglog(string s)
        {
            lock  (locker)
             using (StreamWriter nm = new StreamWriter("log", true, Encoding.UTF8))
             {
                nm.Write(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                nm.Write("--- >  ");
                nm.WriteLine(s);
             }//using
        }

    }//end class
}//end namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Selenium Testing Tools`. 
It will give you full control over web browser / DOM elements and it is very easy to use.